# Text Formatting in itextsharp in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create a pdf file using my C# software. I am using `itextsharp` library to create the customer bill receipt.

However I am not able to format the text. How can we format the text in the pdf file. Only the new line character `\n` seem to be working. How can we format the text using the Tab character ?

Attached is the screen shot of the Text in the pdf file.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

Comment: As the image you provided indicates that you use a proportional font, TAB support would not help. Have you tried using tables to generate your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but I have to contradict Cuong Le, iTextSharp does support TAB Chunks. Please download http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf and look for a section entitled "TAB CHUNKS" (part of section 2.2.6).

As you're asking for a C# solution, let me copy paste the method from iTextSharp you need:

```
/**
 * Creates a tab Chunk.
 * Note that separator chunks can't be used in combination with tab chunks!
 * @param separator the drawInterface to use to draw the tab.
 * @param tabPosition an X coordinate that will be used as start position for the next Chunk.
 * @param newline if true, a newline will be added if the tabPosition has already been reached.
 * @since 2.1.2
 */
public Chunk(IDrawInterface separator, float tabPosition, bool newline)
   : this(OBJECT_REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER, new Font()) {
   if (tabPosition < 0) {
     throw new ArgumentException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("a.tab.position.may.not.be.lower.than.0.yours.is.1", tabPosition));
   }
   SetAttribute(TAB, new Object[] {separator, tabPosition, newline, 0});
}
```

The tab position is a value expressed in user units (by default 1 user unit = 1 point = 1/72 inch). In your case, you need to create such a `Chunk` with the correct tab value (the X value where you want the name and address info to start), and add this 'tab chunk' to the 4 `Paragraph` objects you're adding to the document.

Answer (score 1):

`iTextSharp` does not support `Tab`, but you can use `Paragraph` `Paragraph.IndentationLeft` instead or use `cell.PaddingLeft` for table cell.