# Itext5 not able to render java escape sequence

Tags: java, string, itext, escaping

Using *itextpdf:5.0.6* to preapare a PDF. The text contains java escape sequences (tab: `\t`, newline: `\n`, backspace: `\b`, formfeed: `\f`, carriage return: `\r`).

It is able to render newline but treating tab (`\t`) as a single space. Not able to render formfeed, backspace. Need a way to render the Java string as expected in the PDF.

Font used: Courier
Java String = `Tab\tTab`
Output in pdf = `Tab Tab`

```
Chunk chunk=new Chunk(string)
document.add(chunk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your expectations are the problem: The `Chunk` class simply does neither promise nor implement special handling of those control characters, only `\n` is supported to indicate a line break and `\t` is handled just like a space.

If you need TABs in your code, consider using TAB Chunks (see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207704/1729265)) or section 2.2.6 *The DrawInterface: vertical position marks, separators, and tabs* in iText in Action, 2nd edition (currently you can see the entire book for free [here](https://www.manning.com/books/itext-in-action-second-edition#toc)).

Thus, if you *Need a way to render the Java string as expected in the PDF,* you have to parse your Java string for those control characters, split the string there, and handle each part in a way that results in an appearance as you expect it.

---

As an aside, iText 5.0.6 is ancient. You should consider updating.